# How to render images with proper dimension(width and height) in a grid system of React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am making a eCommerce site where I have to put images of products. So I am using simple CSS Grid system in React but while rendering images they are coming in different sizes , as I have taken images from Web , so they are not adjusting in proper way

Please check my code

```
return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(4 ,1fr)", gridGap: "10px",
      alignContent:"center",padding:"20px",margin:"20px" }}>
        {/* <h1 style={{ color: "green" }}>This is a Clothing Page.</h1> */}

        {filteredClothing[0].products != null &&
          filteredClothing[0].products !== undefined &&
          filteredClothing[0].products.map((item) => (
            <>
              <div style={{}}>
                <Card
                  className="card_image"
                  key={item.id}
                  style={{ width: "70%", height: "100%", padding: "10px",margin:"10px" }}
                >
                  <div style={{display:"flex",flexDirection:"column",flexWrap:"wrap"}}>
                    <div>
                      <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        image={item.image}
                        alt={item.name}
                      ></CardMedia>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <p>Cost: {item.price}</p>
                      <p> {item.description}</p>
                    </div>

                  </div>


                </Card>
              </div>
            </>
```

and inUI it is looking like this
[Products Image in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63aOZ.png)

So I have tried to position elements in DOM but size of image is not changing , for example in Hat image it is rendered according to its size and it is hanging on top
But I am expecting to fit content in the Card and Image size should be constant throughout the application

and I need one more suggestion, if I am using images from Web so thats why it is happening like this or how I have to take images (like from local) ? Please guide me for this also

Thanks

Comment: I have solved it :) for others reference I want to share my code <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        image={item.image}
                        alt={item.name}
                        style={{width:"300px",height:"400px",objectFit:"contain"}}
                      ></CardMedia>
I have used object-fit property
Thanks

Comment: If you have solved the issue, you may write an answer to the question and mark it as the accepted answer (this will close the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got solved by writing CSS property object-fit - "contain" , please check below code:

```
  <CardMedia
    component="img"
    image={item.image}
    alt={item.name}
    style={{
      width: '300px',
      height: '400px',
      objectFit: 'contain',
      cursor: 'pointer',
    }}
    onClick={(event) => showProducts(event, item.id)}
  ></CardMedia>
```